# Finding minimum elements of a matrix for each line - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Here is the example:

I have the following matrix:

```
4 0 3
5 2 6
9 4 8
```

Now, i want to find two minimum values, and their indexes for each row. So the result is:

```
row1: 0 , position (1,2) and 3, position (1,3)
row2...
row3....
```

Well i am using lots of for cycles, and it is pretty complex. So is the any way of using MATLAB function to achieve my goal?

I have tried, but no result:

```
C=min(my_matrix,[],2)
[C(1),I] = MIN(my_matrix(1,:)) &find the position of the minimum value in row 1??
```

Comment: You can use `min` as `[C,I] = min(...)` where `I` involves the linear indices. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html

Comment: I don't understand that result.

Comment: I think `3` is missing after 0 in the result..?

Comment: well as the result I want the "min" value for each row, and it position on matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort each row of your matrix in an ascending order, and then pick the first two indices for each row, like so:

```
[A_sorted, I] = sort(A, 2);
val = A_sorted(:, 1:2)
idx = I(:, 1:2)
```

Now `val` should contain the values of the first two smallest elements in each row, and `idx` should contain their column numbers.

If you want to print everything on the screen in a formatted fashion (as shown in your question), you can use the all-mighty `fprintf` command:

```
rows = (1:size(A, 1))';
fprintf('row %d: %d, position (%d, %d) and %d, position (%d, %d)\n', ...
    [rows - 1, val(:, 1), rows, idx(:, 1), val(:, 2), rows, idx(:, 2)]')
```

#### Example

```
A = [4, 0, 3; 5, 2, 6; 9, 4, 8];

%// Find two smallest values in each row and their positions
[A_sorted, I] = sort(A, 2);
val = A_sorted(:, 1:2)
idx = I(:, 1:2)

%// Print the result
rows = (1:size(A, 1))';
fprintf('row %d: %d, position (%d, %d) and %d, position (%d, %d)\n', ...
    [rows - 1, val(:, 1), rows, idx(:, 1), val(:, 2), rows, idx(:, 2)]')
```

The result is:

```
val =
     0     3
     2     5
     4     8

idx =
     2     3
     2     1
     2     3
```

and the formatted output is:

```
row 0: 0, position (1, 2) and 3, position (1, 3)
row 1: 2, position (2, 2) and 5, position (2, 1)
row 2: 4, position (3, 2) and 8, position (3, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using `sort`.

```
[A_sorted, idx] = sort(A,2); % specify that you want to sort along rows instead of columns
```

The column of `idx` contains the minimum value for each row of `A` and the second column has the index of the second smallest value.

The minimum values can be retrieved from `A_sorted`

Comment: I don't think that this will work. The OP wants to sort each row independently, while this sorts the rows as a group.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below, where `A` is your matrix.

```
[min1, sub1] = min(A, [], 2);  % Gets the min element of each row
rowVec = [1:size(A,1)]';       % A column vector of row numbers to match sub1
ind1 = sub2ind(size(A), rowVec, sub1)  % Gets indices of matrix A where mins are
A2 = A;                        % Copy of A
A2(ind1) = NaN;                % Removes min elements of A
[min2, sub2] = min(A2, [], 2); % Gets your second min element of each row
```

`min1` will be your vector of smallest values, `min2` your vector of second smallest values for each row. Their respective indices for the row will be in `sub1` and `sub2`.